# podspec swift - purple colored icon on left

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

I downloaded a project from [this link](https://github.com/maxep/MXSegmentedPager). In its swift version I can see the pods as follows :

[image]

The pod file has a purple icon(3 hexagons). But when I install the same pod in my project, I don't see this file with such icon - I just get objective-c pod files.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the podfile, it is the MXParallaxHeader module. This is part of the autogenerated bridge.
The MXSegmentedPager is an Objc pod, but it can be used in a swift project by adding `use_frameworks!` to your podfile. The swift bridge will be then generated.